# Scheduled Agents not running in parallel

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

To start with: I'm not really sure whether this question really belongs here or if I should post it at Server Fault; since I'm a developer by trade I'll try here first:

For a major migration project I planned having mutiple scheduled LotusScript Agents each one migrating their own sets of documents. I can use a separate Domino server just for that task so I'm able to set up the maximum of 10 concurrent agents in the server document.

The code is running well, but I'm observing that each one of the agents is waiting for the others to finish. I.e.: no parallel processing.

"show task" at the server console tells me that I indeed have 10 instances of amgr, but 9 of them always being 'idle'.

To verify this I built a set of 4 scheduled test agents each one of them being set up to run every 5 minutes. Their effectivly just waiting, I made sure that each one of them is taking at least 5 minutes to run. The result is as I feared:

all of the agents are using the same amgr executive; the very second that agent #1 terminates agent #2 starts.

"tell amgr schedule" confirms that all 4 agents are scheduled to run "today".

The system this is running on is Domino 9.0.1 FP7 x64 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Is there anything I can do to force my agents that they are truly using all available amgr slots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the agents running in the same database? Domino will only run one scheduled agent at a time for agents within the same database.

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382345/785061

Comment: they are indeed. I really wasn't aware of this (even within 20+ yrs of Domino deveopment I obviously never run into this...). Many thanks!